# How can I search symbian descriptor for multiple words match

Tags: symbian

I have a descriptor and I want to search it for multiple words to see if one of these words are exist or not, How can I do this ?

```
_LIT(KText,"Good Bad Wrong Right False True Now Later What How");
TBuf<100> buf(KText);
```

Now I want to search "**buf**" to see it has (Fasle, Now, Bad) words or at least one of them.

**This is the code below I use, But I don't feel it is sufficient :**

```
  _LIT(KText,"Good;Bad;Now;Later;Why;What");
  TBuf<100>buf(KText);

 _LIT(KWord,"Good;Now");
 TBuf<100>g_Word(KWord);

 TPtrC ptr;
 TChar delimiter;
 delimiter = TChar(';');

 for(TInt ii = 0; ii < 100; ii++)
   {
   if(KErrNone == TextUtils::ColumnText(ptr,ii,&g_Word,delimiter))
       {        
      TBuf<100> temp;temp.Copy(ptr);temp.LowerCase();
      if(KErrNotFound != buf.Find(temp))
        {
      // here I'm gonna do something if there is a match with one or more words in the "buf"
        }
       }
      else
            {
             break;
            }
  }
```

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TDesC has a lot of useful functions.
http://library.forum.nokia.com/index.jsp?topic=/S60_3rd_Edition_Cpp_Developers_Library/GUID-CEE609D8-50E3-422D-8FF9-42C25D669E59_cover.html

```
_LIT16(KFind1,"bad");
TInt index = str.Find(KFind1); /*Will return index if found else returns KErrNotFound*/
```

Comment: Many thanks for your response,But this is suitable if I'm searching for a one word match, So using "Find" means to run a loop over my string to see if it has a match with one of my predefined words; And imagine if I has multiple strings, as when I loop through Inbox SMS'.

My idea is to loop through Inbox and find which SMS has one or more of my predefined words, and after that I'm going to delete this SMS with a match.

So is there a function that takes an array of descriptors and search a string for one or more match ( Note: I don't care how many match in the same SMS).